# With l3 regular expressions, how can I capture a command and replace it with its name?

Tags: l3regex

I have an input of the form òf a clist containing commands, such as `{\my_cmd1,\my_xx_cmd2,\cmd3}`. I first iterate through this list and remove commmas, the backslash `\` etc.

I save the output in a |tl|. I wanted to then remove underscores "_", as it was failing, I tried using regular expressions. This works well for almost everything and maybe is a better approach. How can I remove the `\` using regex and just leave the name of the command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn\my_remove_backslash_comma_and_space:n #1
{
\clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{#1}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_clist
      {
        \expandafter\@gobble\string##1;
      }
   
}


\cs_gset:Npn\test:n#1
{
 \tl_gset:Nn\l_tmpb_tl{\my_remove_backslash_comma_and_space:n{#1}}
 \tl_use:N\l_tmpb_tl
}


\ttfamily

%\tl_set:No\l_tmpa_tl{\test:n{\my_var:NTF, \my_othervar:n}}
\tl_set:No\l_tmpa_tl{my_var:NTF}
% Replace underscores
\regex_replace_all:nnN
{ (_)}
{/}\l_tmpa_tl
\par\tl_use:N\l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN
{(NTF)}
{FALSE}\l_tmpa_tl
\par\tl_use:N\l_tmpa_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: why regex? You can use `\cs_to_str:N` to remove the backslash, and removing an underscore can be done with \str_replace_all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many misconceptions regarding expansion of functions and variables in your code. This will be too much for a comment, so I'm summing them up as part of the answer first, and then come to the real answer how you might remove the underscores.

- `\tl_gset:Nn` shouldn't be used on `\l_tmpb_tl`, as that's a local variable, use local assignments such as `\tl_set:Nn` for local variables instead.
- `\tl_(g)set:Nn` and other assignments (`\clist_set:Nn` for instance) aren't expandable, functions using them should be defined `protected`, so `\cs_gset_protected:Npn \test:n` for instance.
- it is better to use `\cs_new:Npn` to define functions, use `\cs_set:Npn` and friends only if you're changing the definition of a macro you already allocated with a prior `new` variant, or inside a group for a temporary auxiliary macro. so `\cs_new_protected:Npn \test:n` and similar.
- if you only need a `clist` for a single loop, use `\clist_map_inline:nn` instead of `\clist_set:Nn ... \clist_map_inline:Nn`.
- `\tl_set:No` will expand `\test:n` once, which will not set `\l_tmpa_tl` to the final result of `\my_remove_backslash_comma_and_space:n`, but only to a single step of expansion thereof (so it'd start with `\clist_set:Nn`), but setting to the final result isn't possible at all, since `\my_remove_backslash_comma_and_space:n` isn't expandable.

---

Now to the reason why you couldn't remove `_` as easily: After a `\string` the underscores will be of category other (so 12), but the `_` inside of `\ExplSyntaxOn` are of category letter (so 11), and those at the document level of category math subscript (so 8). If you want to use `tl` functions to remove them, you should use the contents of `\c_underscore_str` as your replacement pattern instead. But you can have an easier life if you use the `l3str` functions instead of `l3tl`, since your contents are strings anyway (or at least you want them to become strings).

But things are worse, because when you call your `\regex_replace_all:nnN` the contents of `\l_tmpa_tl` don't contain any underscores at all with your `\test:n`-call (see above, you haven't expanded `\string` on any of the tokens, as your function isn't expanded, and even if you tried to, it'd be unexpandable and you'd most likely get an error).

To set a single variable to the result of your parsing you have two options, either build a function that is fully expandable and use an `e`-type expansion on it, or build a function that sets a variable and manipulates it. The following shows both methods:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l__yannisl_tmpa_str
\cs_new_protected:Npn \yannisl_unexp_remover:Nn #1#2
  {
    \str_clear:N \l__yannisl_tmpa_str
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      { \str_put_right:Ne \l__yannisl_tmpa_str { \cs_to_str:N ##1 } }
    \str_replace_all:Nnn \l__yannisl_tmpa_str { _ } {}
    \str_set_eq:NN #1 \l__yannisl_tmpa_str
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \etl_new_replace_all:Nn { NV }
\etl_new_replace_all:NV \__yannisl_exp_remover_underscore:nn \c_underscore_str
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__yannisl_exp_remover_underscore:nn { e }
\cs_new:Npn \yannisl_exp_remover:n #1
  { \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__yannisl_exp_remover_aux:n }
\cs_new:Npn \__yannisl_exp_remover_aux:n #1
  { \__yannisl_exp_remover_underscore:en { \cs_to_str:N #1 } {} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ttfamily

\yannisl_unexp_remover:Nn \l_tmpa_str { \my_var:NTF, \my_othervar:n }
\token_to_meaning:N \l_tmpa_str

\par

\str_set:Ne \l_tmpa_str
  { \yannisl_exp_remover:n { \my_var:NTF, \my_othervar:n } }
\token_to_meaning:N \l_tmpa_str

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. And thanks again for  your explanation.

Comment: Thanks also for the etl package that I was not aware of. Is this yours?

Comment: @yannisl yes, I wrote it (I originally had a PR adding much of the code of that package to the kernel, but the underlying internal was removed from the kernel in a refactor, and the PR never was merged, so I built my own extended version of that internal and wrote `etl`).

Comment: Two questions ths works well for n items in the list, which can be of n items. Where can I hook for this? Also where exactly s the `\`\`  gobbled? My brain is not working properly these days.

Comment: @yannsil Markdown ate half your second question, I'll assume you mean the backslash. `\cs_to_str:N` removes it. I don't understand what "Where can I hook for this?" means, if you mean "look" the answer for documentation is `interface3.pdf` for everything except the `etl` function used, that is documented in `etl.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks, looked up everything in the docs, and resolved my questions.